# Is there an easy way to hide comma (,) from the end of the indexed words?

Tags: indexing

I use

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

and then I index a word as `\index{word}`.
After `\printindex` in the Index it is appear as

> word, 1

and I want it to appear as

> word 1

But I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prepare a file `<main>.mst`, where `<main>` stands for the name of your main TeX file, containing

```
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
```

and save it in the same folder containing your main file. For instance, if you have `thesis.tex`, you should name the new file as `thesis.mst`.

Then running `makeindex` will load the file and commas will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, and these operators, I mean delim_0, delim_1, delim_2 are just used by makeindex, or by anything else? Will it change other things in my doc?

Comment: They are used by `makeindex`, AFAIR they refer to the three possible indexing levels

Comment: @user153012 The `.mst` file is used just by `makeindex`.

Comment: Really thanks! I have one more question. I think this mst file doesn't know LaTeX codes, so, can I make a little bit more space there then one " " space?

Comment: @user153012 `"\\hspace{2em}"` or `"\\qquad"` will be accepted (escaping the backslash is sufficient).

Comment: @egreg Your answer is useful for me, when I use the command `delim_0 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"` in an arabic polyglossia environment, and I obtain the good arabic comma after the words of the index. But for the multiple entries, the commas between the numbers of the pages' entries are still the latin commas. What's the command for these commas, between the pages'  number ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna This requires a new question with all the needed details.

Comment: Would you see this question opened now. Thank you

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549091/index-and-comma-in-arabic-environment