# Suppress index comma before "see" cross-reference

Tags: indexing

How might the commas between "phrases" and "*see* words" be suppressed in the printed index produced from the source below?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some words.
\index{words}
\index{phrases|see{words}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I'm aware from (http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=21464) that one way to do that is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{(\emph{see} #1)}
\newcommand\gobble[2]{}

\begin{document}

Some words.
\index{words}
\index{phrases \seeonly{words}|gobble}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, I'd like a method that does *not* require adding within each such "see" index entry any explicit code (such as `|gobble`) to suppress the comma. Rather, I seek some way to modify the definition of `\seeonly` itself.

The object is to simplify typing such cross-references in the source document.

(The question is related to: [Change index "see also" and "see" format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format).)

Comment: If you want to get rid of the comma after all the entries (not just the ones which have *see*, then this is a duplicate of [Is there an easy way to hide comma (,) from the end of the indexed words?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197042). If you selectively want a comma for the *see* entries but not the other entries then it's not.

Comment: Alas, not from all entries -- just the ones with *see*.

Comment: A solution appears as part of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format. So the present question could be deleted, or just marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I've added a different solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the answer here:

- [Is there an easy way to hide comma (,) from the end of the indexed words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197042)

We can define an index delimiter to be a macro which tests whether it is followed by the `\see` or the `\seealso` command. This eliminates the need for different indexing commands as in the answer here: [Change index "see also" and "see" format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318472/change-index-see-also-and-see-format)

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 "\\idxdelim"
delim_1 "\\idxdelim"
delim_2 "\\idxdelim"
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\def\idxdelim{\@ifnextchar{\see}{\space}{\@ifnextchar{\seealso}{\space}{, \space}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some words. A test.
\index{words}
\index{phrases|see{words}}
\index{sentences|seealso{words}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: output of index]