# hyperref and imakeidx, custom delimiters

Tags: hyperref, delimiters, imakeidx

Suppose I want to replace the delimiters between pages in my index, so that instead of commas I use semicolons. The following code works well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
        delim_n "; "
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some words. A test.
\index{words}
\index{phrases|see{words}}
\newpage
Words and sentences.\index{words}\index{sentences}
\newpage
Sentences.\index{sentences}

\index{sentences|seealso{words}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, once I uncomment the `hyperref` page, things get weird.

1. We get the log-entry

   ```
    (./testidx3.ind) [4] (./testidx3.aux) )pdfTeX warning (dest):
     name{page.1;2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
   ```
2. Tracing the source, we find that in the generated `.ind` file

   ```
    \begin{theindex}

      \item phrases, \hyperindexformat{\see{words}}{1}

      \indexspace

      \item sentences, \hyperpage{2}; \hyperindexformat{\seealso{words}}{3}; 
                    \hyperpage{3}

      \indexspace

      \item words, \hyperpage{1; 2}

    \end{theindex}
   ```

The culprit is of course `\hyperpage{1; 2}`. It seems that `\hyperref` is relying on the standard choice of delimiters to allow a page range to be passed to `\hyperpage` in one go, instead of having it listed as `\hyperpage{1}; \hyperpage{2}`.

**Question**: Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an user interface, but this here could work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.mst}
        delim_n "; "
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@commahyperpage#1{\@@commahyperpage#1; ;\\}
\def\@@commahyperpage#1; #2;#3\\{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \HyInd@pagelink{#1}%
  \else
    \HyInd@pagelink{#1}; \HyInd@pagelink{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some words. A test.
\index{words}
\index{phrases|see{words}}
\newpage
Words and sentences.\index{words}\index{sentences}
\newpage
Sentences.\index{sentences}

\index{sentences|seealso{words}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: A few follow-up questions: (a) would this break other calls to `\hyperpage` that use the comma syntax? (b) I am a bit surprised that the lack of recursion works; why is it that for two-consecutive pages I get `\hyperpage{1; 2}` but for non-consecutive ones it outputs `\hyperpage{1}; \hyperpage{3}`?

Comment: (a) I have no idea, I simply looked where the commas are and replaced them by ;,  you will have to test if this breaks something. (b) is probably makeindex doing.

Comment: I'll accept this. It helped me learn a bit more how indexing works, and that I was asking the wrong question. Thanks!