# Index and comma in arabic environment

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, makeindex

I want to make an index in arabic environment which is arabic "totally", so where arabic commas are used. From the answer of this question,

[Is there an easy way to hide comma (,) from the end of the indexed words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197042/is-there-an-easy-way-to-hide-comma-from-the-end-of-the-indexed-words/197045?noredirect=1#comment1386848_197045)

I make a `main.mst` file, where `main` stands for the name of my main TeX file, containing

```
delim_0 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
delim_1 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
delim_2 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
```

Note that the arabic comma is pointed to th top. This file gives me the good behaviour for the comma aftet the index entry, but not for those between the pages' numbers for the multiple entries. I give the file used,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\index{word}
\LR{Some text}
\newpage
\index{word}
\LR{Some text}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

and the image of the generated index, where one can see that the comma after (arabic is right-to-left language) the word "word" is the arabic one, and the comma between 1 and 2 are the latin comma.
What's the command changing the comma between 1 and 2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma between the page numbers is set with `delim_n`:

```
delim_0 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
delim_1 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
delim_2 "\\textarabic{،}\\qquad"
delim_n "\\textarabic{،} "
```

[image]

Comment: It's my need. Many thanks